# selecting multiple items in the outliner

Tags: selection-tools, outliner

My question sounds really stupid but I really cant figure how to use multiple selection by dragging mouse cursor instead of clicking one item by another till I select zillion of objects that I need...any tip how to do it quickly?

Thx
Libor

Comment: Instead of using the outliner *Select Pattern* can help to select multiple objects with similar names. If you have added objects to groups you can select by group.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is using the border select with 'b', then if you want to select objects in the scene you can do right click /select

Comment: And this border select can be made more powerful if you use the search in the outliner. Then you could use, sort, border select or even the A key to select all if needed.

Comment: thx much, but it seems that using border select and later right click action doesnt work with left mouse btn assigned for selecting by default... :( or I didnt got it right